# Way to use back button to bring back removed view?

Tags: android

I created a ListView inside of a LinearLayout which again is in a Tab. The list is basically a list of categories which further open into other lists. How I did this is that I just put an OnItemClickListener and after a category is clicked I used removeAllViews() on the LinerLayout and then again added a new ListView of the respective category.

The problem is that pressing the back button from inside a category doesnt go back to the first list, but completely before when there was a list, as the whole thing is occuring in a single Activity. So is it possible to stop that from happening?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, nice question. What will help you in future is to talk about different things you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onBackPressed` to override the action of the BackButton.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something when the BackButton is pressed
    // what you can do is again removeAllViews() from the LinearLayout and redraw your first list
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very quick and helpful :)